# Predicting how long the result of a permutation

Tags: permutations, big-numbers

We're calculating the result of a 'tweaked' Birthday Problem, but when we're calculating, we stumped by a very nasty permutation.

$$10^{576}P_{10^{16}}$$

Which, make us stop working at the number, and call the day.

The formula of the permutation that we understand is:

$$\frac{10^{576}!}{10^{16}!}$$

Is there anyway how do at least 'predict' the length of the number? We already give up on knowing the result, so we just wonder of the massiveness of the number.

Comment: Have you heard about [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation)?

Comment: I haven't. Looking at it!

Comment: There are more digits in this number than there are particles in a multimultiverse containing as many multiverses as there are particles in our universe each containing as many universes as there are particles in our universe...and that doesn't even get close to describing how large this number is. Out of curiousity: what is the 'tweek' in the problem? Are you sure you have calculated correctly? Such numbers are so large that they should never arise...unless you are doing string-theory:)

Answer (score 1):

The number of digits would be about $575* 10^{576}$.  The $10^{16}$ wouldn't even make a dent in that.

On the other hand, I think $10^{576}P_{10^{16}}$ is the product of $10^{16}$ numbers, all very close to $10^{576}$.  That would be $$(10^{576})^{10^{16}}$$ which has $5760000000000000000$ digits.

Comment: 575? Where did the 575 came form? may I know?

Comment: $\log 10^{576}!\approx 10^{576}\log(10^{576})-10^{576}$ in the natural (base-e) logarithm, so that is $10^{576}(\log(10^{576})-1)$.  The number of digits is the common, base-10 logarithm, so $\log_{10}( 10^{576}!)\approx 10^{576}(576-\log_{10} e)\approx 10^{576}(575.6)$